# TFS Listing of all files and version numbers with a particular changeset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, tfs

I'm new to TFS and needing to write a TSQL query to get a listing of all files and version numbers that were included in a particular changeset version number.  While searching online for the tables to get this information I found some people mentioning to use the `Tfs_Warehouse` database and others that used the `Tfs_DefaultCollection` database.  I have the following questions:

- What is the difference between the two databases?
- Why would you use one instead of the other?
- Which tables do you use to obtain the file/version information for a particular changeset?

Comment: +1 for a well written question. I suppose you're aware that you can get this information from Visual Studio by searching History, and then viewing Changeset Details? But I'm assuming that you want to retrieve this programmatically for some other purpose.

Comment: Are you open to writing a .NET application to query this?  Querying the SQL database directly is wholly unsupported.

Comment: That is correct, I'm needing to do it programmatically.  If the TSQL method is unsupported, then is there a way to do it using VB.Net code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [VersionControlServer.GetChangeset() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138628.aspx) from the TFS Object Model.

You will need to add references to the following assemblies in the GAC:

- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client

  ```
  Private Shared Sub Main(ByVal args As String())
      Dim tfs As TfsTeamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(New Uri("http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/CollectionName"), New UICredentialsProvider)
      tfs.Connect(ConnectOptions.None)
      Dim vcs As VersionControlServer = tfs.GetService(Of VersionControlServer)
      Dim changeset As Changeset = vcs.GetChangeset(changeset ID, True, False)
  End Sub
  ```

Then you can inspect the .Changes property to see all the changes included in the Changeset.

Answer (score 9):

If you're looking to get this data from the SQL Server database, here is a query to get you started:

```
SELECT 
    chg_set.CreationDate,
    chg_set.ChangeSetId, 
    v.FullPath
FROM dbo.tbl_ChangeSet (nolock)AS chg_set 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_Version (nolock)AS v ON chg_set.ChangeSetId = v.VersionFrom 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl_File (nolock) AS f ON v.FileId = f.FileId
WHERE (chg_set.ChangeSetId = [Your changeset ID])
ORDER BY chg_set.CreationDate, v.FullPath
```

Source:
http://taoffi.isosoft.org/post/2012/05/23/TFS-database-pause-Change-set-quantitative-statistics-sample

Comment: Why would you query the database directly instead of going through the object model?

Comment: I guess my main reason is "because you can".  I totally understand that you guys don't want people mucking about in the db, and it's officially not supported, but the reality is that it's an option.  I don't recommend playing around in the db if you're not comfortable, but to me, this is the easiest and best way to get results in certain cases.

Comment: Fair enough.  Just curious, really.  If I were a DB guy then I might be more tempted.  (But I'm woefully poor with the SQL.)

Answer (score 0):

Does [`tf.exe changeset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w51xa47k.aspx) not provide the information you want? It's got lots of options...

Comment: I'm needing to do it programmatically, so either via a TSQL query or from within VB.Net.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you calling `tf.exe` programmatically and parsing the output. Of course, if you *want* to learn the TFS API then by all means go for it...